# How to bind events in jquery plugin without overriding existing methods for same events

Tags: jquery

Here is my custom plugin

```
$.fn.custom = function() {
    create: {//some code},
    close: {//some code},
    open: {//some code},
    onClick: {//base on click event handler}
}
```

Now when I use this plugin as

```
someEle.custom({ 
    onClick:{//how to write separate definition here}
    }).custom('open')
```

Comment: This way the click hits the base method of plugin, which I don't want to happen. Also, I don't want to override by instantiating plugin then defining method. Help me find out a way to bind events locally here when plugin is called.

Comment: My point was : please give details by editing your question.

Comment: I think question is quite self-explanatory. What could possibly be explained further ?

Comment: [http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).